# How do I apply a formula in a whole column based off of multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I have an Excel file where data is kept for monthly expenses with supply orders for co-workers. If a co-worker needs a `Head set` let's say, it is put into an Excel sheet with a dollar amount of how much it costs. I want to make it automated so if you enter `Head set` in one cell the dollar amount automatically comes up in the "Total Cost" cell. The problem being that there are multiple items that can be ordered.

I've come up with what I think could be a start but not sure how to implement it. I'm looking for guidance and any suggestions on what to do here.

Column M contains the "supply input" such as `Head set`, `lumbar support`, etc.
Column K contains the "total cost".

```
IF (M16 = Foot Rest, "$20.48","-")
```

However Column M could also contain `Foot Rest`, and `Head set` so that's what's tripping me up. I would like to think that it would contain an extended ELSEIF statement on the above IF statement but I'm unsure how that would work.

Comment: Google `VLOOKUP` which is a function that will provide you with a much easier to maintain approach towards what you would like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to leave a comment, but:

As mentioned, a VLOOKUP as Gareth suggested is your best bet - you would have to build a table of items and prices, and use

```
VLOOKUP(value to lookup(Foot rest in this case),

table to look in (you will usually want to make this static ($A$1:$B$2),

 column to RETURN value from (2 in this case),

and match type (typically you use false/0 for an exact match).
```

Also note, vlookup only tries to match the leftmost column of your array (you will need to use index/match if you want to lookup in another column) - so you find the value in the leftmost column, and return the corresponding value in the (arguement 3)rd column..

(it won't let me post an image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHwwH.png

To answer your question about ELSEIF, you have to nest IFs, so it gets ugly really fast (tip, you can use alt-enter to do a return in the formula):

```
> IF(check1,

true_result,

IF(check2,false_result1,false_result2) 

)
```

So, in your case, IF (M16 = Foot Rest, "$20.48", IF(M16="Headset",12,"-"))

Comment: Good Morning Scott, I'm definitely new to the VLOOKUP Function and understand it to a degree. The only part I don't understand is what the "2,0" is referencing in the picture link you provided. I understand the other references.

Comment: Hi Motorhead, my VLOOKUP is referencing a 2x4 array - the first arguement checks the left most/first column for matches (returns row 4 in this case). The third arguement (2) tells it what column to return from (so my match said "hey, this value was found in row 4", and then the 2 argument will say "ok, in row 4, here is the value in column 2")

Comment: The last argument (0/false) tells vlookup you want an exact match - 1=1, "Foot rest"="Foot rest" will match, 1=2 and "Footrest" = "Foot rest" will not - you can make this an inexact match, which will require a list to be sorted, which has the result of returning the nearest value that does not exceed the searched-for value (in the case that the searched-for value does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

One way for the user to select options is to put your items in a listbox.  This may help with the management/separation/unintentional corruption of your list data and help prevent mistyping by users.  This is an illustrative example only of how you might set-up a (ActiveX) listbox directly on a worksheet.  Some research may also show you additional flexibilities e.g. multi-columns, multi-select of items, pop-out userforms etc.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub slctLbox()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim drng As Range
Dim lBox As MSForms.ListBox
Dim dstrow As Long, dendrow As Long, dstcol As Long, dendcol As Long
Dim lstArr() As Variant

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'location of data
dstcol = 13 'col M
dstrow = 1  'row 1

    'determine data range
    With ws
        dendcol = .Cells(dstrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        dendrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, dstcol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set drng = .Range(.Cells(dstrow, dstcol), .Cells(dendrow, dendcol))
    End With

    Set lBox = Sheets("Sheet1").ListBox1
    'put data into an array
    lstArr = drng
    'setup listbox
    With lBox
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "50"
        'put data array into listbox
        .List = lstArr
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```